# Iterator bug of (more likely) a very subtle behavior?

Tags: c#, linq, iterator

My problem requires 3 (not too long functions) to reproduce (VS2010 / .NET 4)
In the first case, my IEnumerable is not evaluated (through the ToList() method)
I can't see why..

// Main program

```
private void ButtonTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)  
{  
    int[] indexes = new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };  
    var query = Odometer(indexes);  
    // 1) Iterator not evaluated ???  
    var temp = query.ToList();  
    MessageBox.Show(AsString(temp[3]));   

    // 2) OK in this case  
    int count = 0;  
    foreach (int[] item in query)  
    {  
        count++;  
        if (count == 3)  
            MessageBox.Show(AsString(item));  
    }  
}  

/// <summary>  
/// Generate all tuples between 0 and indexes[i]-1  
/// Ex :   
/// Odometer(new int[]{2, 3}); // (0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 2) (1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2)  
/// </summary>  
/// <param name="indexes"></param>  
/// <returns></returns>  
public static IEnumerable<int[]> Odometer(int[] indexes)  
{  
    int[] result = new int[indexes.Length];  
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)  
        result[i] = -1;  

    int ptr = 0;  
    while (ptr >= 0)  
    {  
        while (ptr < indexes.Length)  
        {  
            result[ptr++]++;  
            continue;  
        }  

        ptr--;  
        while (result[ptr] < indexes[ptr])  
        {  
            yield return result;  
            result[ptr]++;  
        }  

        result[ptr]--;  
        while (result[ptr] == indexes[ptr] - 1)  
        {  
            result[ptr] = -1;  
            ptr--;  
            if (ptr < 0)  
                break;  
        }  
    }  
}  

/// <summary>  
/// Format an IList of T    
/// </summary>  
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>  
/// <param name="array"></param>  
/// <returns></returns>  
private static string AsString<T>(IList<T> array)  
{  
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();  
    foreach (T item in array)  
        builder.AppendFormat("{0}, ", item);  
    if (builder.Length >= 2)  
        builder.Length -= 2;  
    return builder.ToString();  
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help
Philippe

Comment: How do you determine if the IEnumerable is evaluated?

Comment: In the first case, temp has the right size but constains a list of {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1}

Answer (score 5):

Your IEnumerable is runned when:

```
var temp = query.ToList();
```

I made a break point in Odometer and sure enough it breaked. It contains a lots of list of -1. Maybe you need a better Odometer method?

**EDIT:** The problem is that you are yield returning the same array all the time. So it will always have the same value. You should read something about references in .Net/C#. Also, the method does only need the length so only send the length with it.

```
public static IEnumerable<int[]> Odometer(int[] indexes)
{
    int[] result = new int[indexes.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
        result[i] = -1;

    int ptr = 0;
    while (ptr >= 0)
    {
        while (ptr < indexes.Length)
        {
            result[ptr++]++;
            continue;
        }

        ptr--;
        while (result[ptr] < indexes[ptr])
        {
            //HERE
            //Clones the array so you are returning a new array - thanks Jon, for improvement on the Array.Copy code.
            yield return result.ToArray();

            result[ptr]++;
        }

        result[ptr]--;
        while (result[ptr] == indexes[ptr] - 1)
        {
            result[ptr] = -1;
            ptr--;
            if (ptr < 0)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for "Maybe you need a better Odometer method".  The bug is probably in that class.

Answer (score 3):

As lasseespeholt says, the problem is that you're repeatedly yielding references to the same array, then mutating that array.

Calling `ToList()` will iterate over the whole iterator, so you'll end up with a list of the same reference multiple times, and by the time you examine the contents it will all be -1.

One simple fix is to change Odometer's yield return statement to:

```
yield return result.ToArray();
```

This will clone the array at the point where you yield it, so the list will have *different* array references.

Comment: Hi Jon,

Thanks for taking the time and your clear answer: it's obvious now that you have said it. A stupid ref error.

Philippe
PS:
I have your book "C# id Depth". Great.