# Get next N elements from enumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enumerator

Context: C# 3.0, .Net 3.5
Suppose I have a method that generates random numbers (forever):

```
private static IEnumerable<int> RandomNumberGenerator() {
    while (true) yield return GenerateRandomNumber(0, 100);
}
```

I need to group those numbers in groups of 10, so I would like something like:

```
foreach (IEnumerable<int> group in RandomNumberGenerator().Slice(10)) {
    Assert.That(group.Count() == 10);
}
```

I have defined Slice method, but I feel there should be one already defined. Here is my Slice method, just for reference:

```
    private static IEnumerable<T[]> Slice<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int size) {
        var result = new List<T>(size);
        foreach (var item in enumerable) {
            result.Add(item);
            if (result.Count == size) {
                yield return result.ToArray();
                result.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Question:** is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Perhaps Linq?

Note: above example is a simplification, in my program I have an Iterator that scans given matrix in a non-linear fashion.

**EDIT:** Why `Skip`+`Take` is no good.

Effectively what I want is:

```
var group1 = RandomNumberGenerator().Skip(0).Take(10);
var group2 = RandomNumberGenerator().Skip(10).Take(10);
var group3 = RandomNumberGenerator().Skip(20).Take(10);
var group4 = RandomNumberGenerator().Skip(30).Take(10);
```

without the overhead of regenerating number (10+20+30+40) times. I need a solution that will generate exactly 40 numbers and break those in 4 groups by 10.

Comment: Why do you want to enumerate it than? Just pass number of random numbers you want to generate and than return a collection of random numbers.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the `RandomNumberGenerator` code you posted is not actual code that you are using? Because it looks to me like it should only return a single value, rather than enumerating forever (for that you would need to use a looping construct).

Comment: @user93422, wouldn't it be easier to create a generator context class and provide a `GetNext()` and `GetNext(int count)` rather than trying to slice up an infinite enumeration?  This is the design that the Random class uses and it's a clean way to accomplish what you're after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have done something similar. But I would like it to be simpler:

```
//Remove "this" if you don't want it to be a extension method
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> Chunks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> xs, int size)
{
    var curr = new List<T>(size);

    foreach (var x in xs)
    {
        curr.Add(x);

        if (curr.Count == size)
        {
            yield return curr;
            curr = new List<T>(size);
        }
    }
}
```

I think yours are flawed. You return the same array for all your chunks/slices so only the last chunk/slice you take would have the correct data.

**Addition:** Array version:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> Chunks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> xs, int size)
{
    var curr = new T[size];

    int i = 0;

    foreach (var x in xs)
    {
        curr[i % size] = x;

        if (++i % size == 0)
        {
            yield return curr;
            curr = new T[size];
        }
    }
}
```

**Addition:** Linq version (not C# 2.0). As pointed out, it will not work on infinite sequences and will be a great deal slower than the alternatives:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> Chunks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> xs, int size)
{
    return xs.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
             .GroupBy(xi => xi.i / size, xi => xi.x)
             .Select(g => g.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: right, I suppose me using array instead of list is an example of premature optimization. BTW, why do you use `(++i % size == 0)` instead of `curr.Length == size`? also your `curr = new List<T>()` should be `curr = new List<T>(size)`

Comment: Yes, I was reusing same array (worked for my case, but that might be a bug in most cases).

Comment: I do use `(size)` both places, I guess you got a early version :) I don't think `List` will be much slower than arrays. Because then I don't have to reset index each time. It would have been a bug if you did a `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` but if you process the data immediately then it will be fine. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447355/iterator-bug-of-more-likely-a-very-subtle-behavior/3447397#3447397

Comment: Your right, I could have been using `.Count` instead. Thanks for improving :)

Comment: well if I'd use ToList or ToArray - that would actually fix the bug, since that would create a new instance on each `yield return`. no?

Comment: Yes, but I would guess that my method is faster because it ain't copying the list to an array - but I have not tested it.

Comment: The difference in the return, I return T[] chunks, when you do IList<T> - that's what makes a difference, too bad there is no (`(T[]) list`)

Comment: The array internally in a list can be larger than the actual list, so either it could return a larger array than you want or do the same as ToArray() - unless of cause the array and list size is equal.

Comment: See my linq version. I think it looks nice. You may be able to convert it to C# 2.0

Comment: my bad. I **am** using C# 3.0, not 2.0

Comment: one caveat, linq version will not work with infinite sequence. For my real case it does what it supposed to do.

Comment: The LINQ version is nice, but has the disadvantage of consuming all of `xs` before returning the first slice. GroupBy can't know that there isn't another item with a key of 0 until it has read everything. For a typical enumerable that's just different to the other implementations rather than really wrong, but for the infinite random number generator it means an infinite loop.

Comment: @user93422,stevemegson Yeah, it must also be a lot slower than the alternatives. I have pointed it out in my answer.

Answer (score 12):

Are [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) of any use to you?

Use a combination of the two in a loop to get what you want.

So,

```
list.Skip(10).Take(10);
```

Skips the first 10 records and then takes the next 10.

Comment: I don't want overhead of Skip/Take, I have edited the question.

Comment: I don't think this will work how you think it will with a generator.

Answer (score 8):

Using `Skip` and `Take` would be **a very bad idea**. Calling `Skip` on an indexed collection may be fine, but calling it on any arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>` is liable to result in enumeration over the number of elements skipped, which means that if you're calling it repeatedly you're enumerating over the sequence **an order of magnitude more times than you need to be**.

Complain of "premature optimization" all you want; but that is just ridiculous.

I think your `Slice` method is about as good as it gets. I was going to suggest a different approach that would provide deferred execution and obviate the intermediate array allocation, but that is a dangerous game to play (i.e., if you try something like `ToList` on such a resulting `IEnumerable<T>` implementation, without enumerating over the inner collections, you'll end up in an endless loop).

(I've removed what was originally here, as the OP's improvements since posting the question have since rendered my suggestions here redundant.)

Comment: I have changed the implementation to use foreach instead, that should take care of disposing. good point though +1

Comment: `yield return result.ToArray();` ensures that every returned chunk is a unique array-object.

Comment: @user93422: Yes, I see that we came up with the same solution to that issue. Your original code did return the same array, though, as you yourself conceded.

Comment: Why not use a foreach when you are doing just what the foreach-loop does?

Comment: @lasseespeholt: Good question; really my code was just a modified version of what the OP had originally. I can't really give much of a reason, other than that it didn't occur to me. `foreach` would be more readable.

Answer (score 2):

**Let's see if you even need the complexity of Slice.** If your random number generates is stateless, I would assume each call to it would generate unique random numbers, so perhaps this would be sufficient:

```
var group1 = RandomNumberGenerator().Take(10);  
var group2 = RandomNumberGenerator().Take(10);  
var group3 = RandomNumberGenerator().Take(10);  
var group4 = RandomNumberGenerator().Take(10);
```

Each call to `Take` returns a new group of 10 numbers.

**Now, if your random number generator re-seeds itself** with a specific value each time it's iterated, this won't work. You'll simply get the same 10 values for each group. So instead, you would use:

```
var generator  = RandomNumberGenerator();
var group1     = generator.Take(10);  
var group2     = generator.Take(10);  
var group3     = generator.Take(10);  
var group4     = generator.Take(10);
```

This maintains an instance of the generator so that you can continue retrieving values without re-seeding the generator.

Comment: `yield result.ToArray()` clones data into a new array, so calling `Clear()` on the list will not affect the returned instance of the array.

Comment: @user93422: Yes I noticed that shorty after updating my post. I've corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(VS.90).aspx) methods with any Enumerable object.

**For your edit :**

How about a function that takes a slice number and a slice size as a parameter?

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Slice<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int sliceSize, int sliceNumber) {
    return enumerable.Skip(sliceSize * sliceNumber).Take(sliceSize);
}
```

Comment: it will still dry-run enumerable for slices to be skipped. I'd like to avoid dry runs (performance is an official excuse, but actually it just feels wrong). Also your example enumerates T's not T[]'s as it should have (but I get the point).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like we'd prefer for an `IEnumerable<T>` to have a fixed position counter so that we can do

```
var group1 = items.Take(10);
var group2 = items.Take(10);
var group3 = items.Take(10);
var group4 = items.Take(10);
```

and get successive slices rather than getting the first 10 items each time. We can do that with a new implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` which keeps one instance of its Enumerator and returns it on every call of GetEnumerator:

```
public class StickyEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IDisposable
{
    private IEnumerator<T> innerEnumerator;

    public StickyEnumerable( IEnumerable<T> items )
    {
        innerEnumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return innerEnumerator;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return innerEnumerator;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (innerEnumerator != null)
        {
            innerEnumerator.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Given that class, we could implement Slice with

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Slices<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int size)
{
    using (StickyEnumerable<T> sticky = new StickyEnumerable<T>(items))
    {
        IEnumerable<T> slice;
        do
        {
            slice = sticky.Take(size).ToList();
            yield return slice;
        } while (slice.Count() == size);
    }
    yield break;
}
```

That works in this case, but `StickyEnumerable<T>` is generally a dangerous class to have around if the consuming code isn't expecting it. For example,

```
using (var sticky = new StickyEnumerable<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10)))
{
    var first = sticky.Take(2);
    var second = sticky.Take(2);
    foreach (int i in second)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    foreach (int i in first)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

prints

```
1
2
3
4
```

rather than

```
3
4
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Take(), TakeWhile() and Skip()

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of `Slice()` would be a bit misleading. I think of that as a means to give me a chuck of an array into a new array and not causing side effects. In this scenario you would actually move the enumerable forward 10.

A possible better approach is to just use the Linq extension `Take()`. I don't think you would need to use `Skip()` with a generator.

**Edit:** Dang, I have been trying to test this behavior with the following code

**Note:** this is wasn't really correct, I leave it here so others don't fall into the same mistake.

```
var numbers = RandomNumberGenerator();
var slice = numbers.Take(10);

public static IEnumerable<int> RandomNumberGenerator()
{
    yield return random.Next();
}
```

but the `Count()` for `slice` is alway 1. I also tried running it through a `foreach` loop since I know that the Linq extensions are generally lazily evaluated and it only looped once. I eventually did the code below instead of the `Take()` and it works:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Slice(this IEnumerable<int> enumerable, int size)
{
    var list = new List<int>();
    foreach (var count in Enumerable.Range(0, size)) list.Add(enumerable.First());
    return list;
}
```

If you notice I am adding the `First()` to the list each time, but since the enumerable that is being passed in is the generator from `RandomNumberGenerator()` the result is different every time.

So again with a generator using `Skip()` is not needed since the result will be different. Looping over an `IEnumerable` is not always side effect free.

**Edit:** I'll leave the last edit just so no one falls into the same mistake, but it worked fine for me just doing this:

```
var numbers = RandomNumberGenerator();

var slice1 = numbers.Take(10);
var slice2 = numbers.Take(10);
```

The two slices were different.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I failed to construct an actual method using that idea. Care to produce a snippet?

Comment: I hope that helps at least some what. I probably should brush up on generators myself.

Comment: @Sean: Your `RandomNumberGenerator` function returns a single value. You would need to put it in a loop: `while (true) yield return random.Next();`

Comment: how do you change Slice method so it returns `IEnumerable<int[]>` without calling `enmerable.Count()`? And does yield return instead of return, what you have right now is exactly: `return enumerable.Take(size);`...I think.

Comment: I'll add my adaptation to a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had made some mistakes in my original answer but some of the points still stand. Skip() and Take() are not going to work the same with a generator as it would a list. Looping over an IEnumerable is not always side effect free. Anyway here is my take on getting a list of slices.

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> RandomNumberGenerator()
    {
        while(true) yield return random.Next();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> Slice(this IEnumerable<int> enumerable, int size, int count)
    {
        var slices = new List<List<int>>();
        foreach (var iteration in Enumerable.Range(0, count)){
            var list = new List<int>();
            list.AddRange(enumerable.Take(size));
            slices.Add(list);
        }
        return slices;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution for the same problem:

```
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> chunks = Chunk(ints, 2, t => t.Dump());
//won't enumerate, so won't do anything unless you force it:
chunks.ToList();

IEnumerable<T> Chunk<T, R>(IEnumerable<R> src, int n, Func<IEnumerable<R>, T> action){
  IEnumerable<R> head;
  IEnumerable<R> tail = src;
  while (tail.Any())
  {
    head = tail.Take(n);
    tail = tail.Skip(n);
    yield return action(head);
  }
}
```

if you just want the chunks returned, not do anything with them, use `chunks = Chunk(ints, 2, t => t)`. What I would really like is to have to have `t=>t` as default action, but I haven't found out how to do that yet.