# How do you pass a lambda function into a regular function as a default value for a conditional argument?

Tags: vb.net

The following:

```
Delegate Function OperationDelegate(ByVal x As Double) As Double
Public Function test(Optional ByRef operation As OperationDelegate = AddressOf DefaultOperation) As Double
    Return operation.Invoke(3)
End Function
```

gives me the error: Constant Expression is required. Addressof DefaultOperation is causing the error using Visual Studio 2013.

I have tried defining DefaultOperation in the two following ways.

```
Public Function DefaultOperation(ByVal x As Double) As Double
    Return x
End Function

Dim DefaultOperation As OperationDelegate = Function(x As Double) As Double
                                                Return x
                                            End Function
```

In either case it has not worked.
This is the ressource I have been using: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx

Anyways thanks for your time.

A similar questions that I found:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304320/specifying-a-default-value-for-an-optional-anonymous-function-parameter-in-vb-ne
- [lambda as default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140348/lambda-as-default-argument)

Comment: As you can see from the similar questions you linked to. The default value for an optional argument must be a constant (its value must be known at compile time). It can't be a lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments on your original post, a lambda can not be used as an optional parameter.

An alternative would be to overload the function (test, in your example) with a version with no parameters and a version with a delegate parameter.

```
Delegate Function OperationDelegate(ByVal x As Double) As Double

Public Function test() As Double
   Return test(AddressOf OperationDelegate)
End Function

Public Function test(operation As OperationDelegate) As Double
   Return operation.Invoke(3)
End Function
```