# How can I join strings from one List<string> into another one?

Tags: c#

I've got `List<string> Names;`, it has 700 000 names in it. How can I join every 500 strings (using separator ",") and add them to new `List<string> ABC;`

So I want to have one `List<string>`, that will hold 1400 joined strings.

ABC[0]= first 500 names, ABC[1]= next 500 names and so on.

Comment: You want to take 500 strings out of the first list, concatenate them with a ',' in between and insert them into the ABC list? Is that correct?

Comment: @Sossenbinder yes, It is.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) Batch (or [any other batch implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731796/create-batches-in-linq)):

```
var abc = names.Batch(500).Select(x => String.Join(",", x)).ToList();
```

NOTE: Grouping operator is not [streaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx) operator (as well as ToList). That means that all 700k strings should be enumerated and keys should be calculated for each item, and each items should be stored in internal groups. And that will cost some time and resources. Batching is streaming and it does not store all items internally. It stores only current batch. So with batching *if you will not convert results to list*, you can process batches one by one faster and save some memory.

Comment: Damn, I just wanted to answer with a loop attempt, but that LINQ is just too elegant to pass up here. That's a beautiful one liner.

Comment: "It stores only current batch." Yep, but note that the code I posted doesn't even store the current batch ;) (Although it's not threadsafe). It's marginally faster than MoreLINQ's implementation, by about 15%

Comment: @MatthewWatson yeah, with `ToList()` at the end enumerating will work.. but if one of items will not be enumerated fully.. :) Though in this particular case it will work - seems like OP wants all items anyway

Comment: Good point about fully enumerating it.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you can do it with LINQ:

```
var result =
    Names
        .Select((item, index) => new {Item = item, Index = index})
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 500)
        .Select(g => string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Item)))
        .ToList();
```

First, for each item, you select the item it self along with its index. Then you group these items by `index / 500` which means that each 500 items will be grouped together.

Then you use `string.Join` to join the 500 strings in each group together.

Comment: I would personally avoid this approach for large lists, since it makes an additional copy of all the strings.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I am not really sure about this. LINQ should be efficient. To be sure, in cases of large data, I always measure the time and memory consumption of such queries, and if there are issues I look for other approaches.

Comment: I just meant in terms of memory. It makes a copy of the entire list into dictionary before returning the result. I guess it will be fast though - since GroupBy() is O(N). (I did some timings and this is roughly 4 times slower than using a dedicated batcher.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson, you mean because of `GroupBy`, right? I think you probably have a point. OP should measure memory consumption and see if it is acceptable for them. Most of the times this is not a problem.

Comment: It's the 700,000 strings that was worrying me. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use a separate library, you can use a simple extension method to partition a sequence into subsequences of a given size:

```
public static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int blockSize)
    {
        var enumerator = input.GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield return nextPartition(enumerator, blockSize);
    }

    static IEnumerable<T> nextPartition<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int blockSize)
    {
        do    yield return enumerator.Current;
        while (--blockSize > 0 && enumerator.MoveNext());
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
        // Create some sample strings.
        var strings = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();

        var result = strings.Partition(500).Select(block => string.Join(",", block)).ToList();
```

This approach does not make a copy of the input array.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way is to use LINQ Chunks implementation [from SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3524511/5649561):

```
List<string> ABC = Names.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                        .GroupBy(xi => xi.i / 500, xi => xi.x)
                        .Select(g => string.Join(",", g))
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        string[] strs = new string[]{"aaaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eeee","fff","ggg","hhhh","iiiii","JJJJ"};
        List<string> res=new List<string>();
        for(int i=0;i<strs.Length;i+=5){
            res.Add(string.Join(",",strs,i,5));
        }
        res.ForEach(F => Console.WriteLine(F));
    }
```

just change the iteration to be with 500 instead of 5, and strs to be your array.